# (How) can I create a tmpfs as a regular (non-root) user?

Tags: linux, filesystems, tmpfs

The distribution is an Ubuntu server running the 2.6.35-30 Linux kernel.

I would like to have a directory that sits completely in memory. Is this possible without root privileges?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Linux provides a tmpfs device which any user can use, `/dev/shm`.  It is not mounted to a specific directory by default, but you can still use it as one.

Simply create a directory in `/dev/shm` and then symlink it to wherever you want.  You can give the created directory any permissions you choose, so that other users can't access it.

This is a RAM backed device, so what's there is in memory by default.  You can create any directories you need inside `/dev/shm`

Naturally, files placed here will not survive a reboot, and if your machine starts swapping, `/dev/shm` won't help you.

The Solaris parallel to `/dev/shm` is `/tmp` which is a "swap" type partition, and also memory based.  As with `/dev/shm`, arbitrary users may create files in `/tmp` on Solaris.

OpenBSD has the capability to use a memory based mount as well, but does not have one available by default.  The mount_mfs command is availabe to the super user.

I'm not sure about other *BSDs.

Comment: A symlink could solve the *where* problem.

Comment: D'oh... forgot about those pesky little symlinks.

Comment: @enzotib fixed it!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `/dev/tmpfs` on the system (neither does my own system which has a 3.0.0 kernel). Are you sure that's not something created by your distribution?

Comment: Ah, on my system, `/dev/tmpfs` is called `/dev/shm` as noted by Gilles.

Comment: Hmm... not sure how that changed, I swear I wrote /dev/shm originally.  Very strange.  Fixed now.

Comment: @Gabe, would not that warrant to have any configuration like shm parameters in sysctl.conf (Atleast in Solaris, they need to be updated in /etc/system)

Comment: @Nikhil on linux, at least ubuntu it is enabled and configured by default, ready for use.  The solaris version of this is /tmp, which seems also to be available by default, no configuration needed.

Comment: Not sure if this apply's to others as well, but on my current version of ubuntu this seems to have changed to `/run` and possibly `/run/shm` Need to investigate further before updating my answer.

Comment: In Debian `/dev/shm` is indeed symlinked to `/run/shm`.

Answer (score 24):

## /dev/shm is not suitable for secrets

...on systems with active [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)! Chances are **very high** your computer has it enabled.

There is a better, **guaranteed ephemeral**, standard alternative — `ramfs`. You may want to use `ramfs` if you plan to use RAM-backed space to **temporary** store sensitive data, such as private keys, Bitcoin or Ethereum wallets and such.

`ramfs` is better than `tmpfs` when data needs to be secret, since `ramfs` data **never** gets swapped (saved to a physical storage drive), while `tmpfs` **may** get swapped. Third parties who later gain root or physical access to the machine then **can inspect the swap space** and **extract sensitive data**.

### The solution

You can prepare `ramfs` mount so any non-privileged user can mount/unmount it on-demand.

To do this, you will need **root** privilege, **once**. Ask the administrator of your system to set this up for you, if you lack root privileges.

At first, you need to add a line to the `/etc/fstab`. The line in `fstab` may look like this:

```
none    /mnt/ramfs    ramfs    noauto,user,size=1024M,mode=1777    0    0
```

- `/mnt/ramfs` is a mount point, where the ramfs filesystem will be mounted. Directory **should exist**.
- `noauto` option prevents this from being mounted automatically (e.g. at system's boot up).
- `user` makes this mountable by regular users.
- `size` sets this "ramdisk's" size (you can use `M` and `G` here). It has no effect though, as the ramdisk will grow as needed.
- `mode` is **very important**, with the octal code `1777` any user is allowed to create files and directories, but only owners of those files and directories will be able to access them (you may use different code of your choice as well, but be very sure about it!).

When this is done, any user will be able to mount this on demand.

Once some user mounts this, new `ramfs` filesystem is created and mounted at `/mnt/ramfs/`. It will be owned by `root:user`. Once he/she unmounts it, or system gets rebooted, this RAM-based filesystem will **vanish** with **all** its data. Which is cool.

Also, this filesystem can be mounted by several users independently, but **not at the same time**, i.e. to be ready for mounting by a next user, previous user should unmount this filesystem. Or you can create individual filesystems for each user.

**to mount:**

```
mount /mnt/ramfs/
```

**to unmount:**

```
umount /mnt/ramfs/
```

P.S. If you are trying to `rsync` files to the root of the newly mounted/created ramfs as a non-root user, you may face a `rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]` error. This is completely fine and expected, because your user doesn't own the root of the ram filesystem. Solution is simple, just create some directory there, `/mnt/ramfs/copied/` for example, and `rsync` into it.

P.P.S. Tested on Debian 9. Pretty sure it'll work on Ubuntu, too.

P.P.P.S. Although vastly more secure, RAM-based storage is **still vulnerable** to some elaborate attacks, like the [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack). So if you are really serious about security of your data, make sure to **physically** secure your PC/laptop, lock the case and memory sticks, or even better, consider using a computer with a RAM soldered right into the motherboard (which is the case for most higher tier ultraportable laptops). Also consider to fully shut down your computer if you don't intend to use it in the next hour or so. Maybe even go so far as to disable sleep/hibernation features altogether.

Comment: The `size` option has no effect on ramfs. Unlike tmpfs, it can grow until RAM is exhausted.

Comment: You can use "sticky bit" to allow any user to create files and directories. That is `mode=1777`. Only owners of those files and directories will be able to access them. This is how it is implemented for standard */tmp* directory.

Comment: Thank you guys, I incorporated your comments into the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Your system may have one already available; recent Linux systems based on Glibc always [have a tmpfs mounted on `/dev/shm`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/how-can-i-create-a-tmpfs-as-a-regular-non-root-user/26366#26366).

If your system doesn't have one or it's too small, then a filesystem not mounted by root pretty much means [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). On Ubuntu, you need to be in the `fuse` group to use FUSE. Looking through [available FUSE filesystems](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems), I see only [Ramfuse](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=33370), which unfortunately is abandoned upstream.

Answer (score 5):

In general, no, filesystems can only be mounted by root. If you allow a user to place filesystems arbitrarily, that's essentially giving them root. (Easy way: mount one over /etc, put your own passwd and shadow there, su with the new root password you just created, unmount)

If you want a tmpfs at a particular location, you could add it to `/etc/fstab`, with the flags of `noauto,user` and then a user would be able to mount it (but its not particularly clear why you wouldn't just auto-mount it)

If users need arbitrary tmpfs's, then you have a couple options:

- use subdirectories of one tmpfs. Probably the best approach. You really probably don't need more than one tmpfs.
- create a script that will create a directory and mount a tmpfs over it, and then print out where it put it. Use `sudo` to allow users to run it. Make sure that you do *not* allow the user to pick arbitrary paths.