# mount same tmpfs on two mountpoints

Tags: fstab, tmpfs

I have this in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs   /home/user1/tmp tmpfs  rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec,size=16G  0   0
```

`user1` has `tmpfs` mounted as `/home/user1/tmp`.

I would like to mount same `tmpfs` for `user2` as well, so that they can share same tmpfs.

How can I do this in `fstab`, so that `user2` has same `tmpfs` mounted at /home/user1/tmp ?

Comment: Don't you also have a `uid` option in your `fstab`? In other words, is the mounted tmpfs currently only accessible to root? What should eventually be the two users' access permissions to the tmpfs?

Comment: @fra-san - thank you, you are right. I have removed the mode because it is no relevant here. But in my real fstab, I have mode,uid, and gid

Comment: I believe the permissions you're expecting `user1` and `user2` to have over the mounted tmpfs are relevant: for instance (on Linux -- you didn't specify your platform, which may be relevant too), you may just symlink `/home/user1/tmp` and `/home/user2/tmp` [to `/dev/shm`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26364/315749) (or bind-mount it), if you're OK with its sticky bit - i.e. both users can read everything but only edit and remove files and directories they own.

Comment: @fra-san - I cannot symlink, because the users don't have access to each others homes. Anyway, please forget about permissions. This is not the issue here. I know how to fix that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another line with a bind mount:

```
/home/user1/tmp /home/user2/tmp none bind,x-systemd.requires=/home/user1/tmp
```

The systemd is just for ordering, but you may not need/want it.

Comment: thank you. That works.